# how i get primary key in string format in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

i'm currently working on django rest framework project and the requirement of output of the response is described below.

if any one have an idea about this, it will be very helpful for me.

currently i'm getting output like this:

```
{
    "status": true,
    "message": "User Details",
    "Detail": {
        "id": 1,
        "phone": "9874563120",
        "first_name": "Crish",
        "birthdate": "1989-09-16",
        "age": 32,
        "email": "crish@gmail.com",

    }
}
```

But i want to get output like this:

```
    {
    "status": true,
    "message": "User Details",
    "Detail": {
        "id": "1", #in string formate
        "phone": "9874563120",
        "first_name": "Crish",
        "birthdate": "1989-09-16",
        "age": "32", #in string formate
        "email": "crish@gmail.com",

    }
}
```

what change should i make to gat this type of output!

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution on this problem you just need to add few lines in your serializer class.

i assume your `serializers.py` file looks like this :

`serializers.py`

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer): #Assumed class name 

class Meta:
    model = User #Assumed model name 
    fields = ['id','phone','first_name','birthdate','age','email']

#you just need to add following representation function after your `Meta class`

def to_representation(self, instance):
    repr = super().to_representation(instance)
    repr['id'] = str(repr['id'])
    repr['age'] = str(repr['age'])

    return repr
```

> it'll resolve your problem :)